# Dividing a task into smaller section (multiple threads)

Tags: android, multithreading

In order to decrease task time I want to split that to 254 threads!

```
   for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++) {

       final String ipAddress = host + i;

       Thread thread = new Thread() {
           @Override
           public void run() {

              // ping IP address
           }
       };

       thread.start();
   }
```

In the serial way it takes about 12.7 minutes long, but by using split to 254 threads that mentioned above all of IP's pinged in ~3 seconds!

Now I want to know is there any potential problem with my approach? or have I done this in efficient way?

Comment: *In the usual way*, what usual way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it more efficient by using a thread pool and save the overhead for creating a new thread in each iteration. Try to use a different number of threads in the pool and measure the running time so you'll get the best configuration for your scenario.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html

Comment: I know that each ping will take 3 seconds, so if I have 10 threads the hole process will takes ~25*3 seconds! nevertheless you recommend to use less threads?

Comment: I'm just suggesting to check if the thread creation is a factor here. Try it for 50, 100 and 150 threads and check if you see an improvement.